# Early execution of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ienumerable

So I have two methods both performing iteration through `IEnumerable` collection.

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRange(int start, int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

        var end = start + count;

        for (int value = start; value < end; value++)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRangeFunction(int start, int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

        var end = start + count;
        return RangeEnumeration();

        //Using local function
        IEnumerable<int> RangeEnumeration()
        {
            for (var value = start; value < end; value++)
            {
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I recently came to know method returning `IEnumerable` will not execute until enumerated.

So I created two blocks of code to call each method

**Calling GetRange**

```
var iterator = GetRange(0, 10); // This does not start the execution of `GetRange` method. Instead, it waits till any item is requested
foreach(var item in iterator) //Now the GetRange method is called
{

}
```

**GetRangeFunction**

But, in the case of `GetRangeFunction`, the method is called right away on creating the iterator.

```
var iterator = GetRangeFunction(0, 5);
```

Why is this behaviour? I was thinking `GetRangeFunction` also, won't execute until an item is requested.

**EDIT**

My question is poorly stated, let me try to explain it one more time.

Both the enumerators are returning items via yield one after other. But in the case of **GetRange**, no statement (`not even checking count is less than zero`) is executed until any operation is done on the enumerator. But, in case of **GetRangeFunction** the condition check is executed when the method is called to create the iterator.

Comment: `will not be executed until enumerated` -  it will be executed to the point where it returns the enumerator object. For plain iterator functions, that would be *straight away* which you may have perceived as "did not execute".

Comment: Is it during compile time only these decisions are made? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The code is compiled at compile time. It may contain different execution paths that return different [enumerator objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) based on various conditions which is decided at runtime. In any case the returned enumerator object will not be enumerated until it explicitly is with e.g. a `foreach`.

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine` before iterator loop and before yield return. See what happens.

Comment: @Steve, @GSerg that's not actually true. The entire method that uses `yield` would only be executed upon enumeration

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @haim770 You seem to be using a different definition for "be executed". An iterator method is still just a method, it still *has to* execute and return a value when called. It's just that the value it returns is a state machine that will not be touched until later.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Please see [The implementation of iterators in C# and its consequences (part 1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273). The compiler converts the *entire* `IEnumerable<int> GetRange` into a state machine, so no code from it is executed until enumerated. But `IEnumerable<int> GetRangeFunction` is not converted to a state machine at all, only the `IEnumerable<int> RangeEnumeration()` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), local function can allow exceptions to surface immediately. For example, consider the following code.

```
        static void Main()
        {            
            IEnumerable<int> ienum = GetNumber(50, 110);
            //below line will not execute if use GetNumberByLocalMethod
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved enumerator...");

            foreach (var i in ienum)
            {
                Console.Write($"{i} ");
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumberByLocalMethod(int start, int end)
        {
            throw new Exception("deliberately exception");
            return InnerGetNumberByLocalMethod();
            IEnumerable<int> InnerGetNumberByLocalMethod()
            {
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                {                    
                        yield return i;
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumber(int start, int end)
        {
            throw new Exception("deliberately exception");

            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {                
                    yield return i;
            }
        }
```

To make sure local method version can get exception quickly, GetNumberByLocalMethod version will execute immediately and not wait until the first iterate.

Comment: I believe that this is just because the local method is considered a separate method body and can only work if all captured variables are calculated. Since the outer method body of `GetNumberByLocalMethod` has no `yield` statements it can be evaluated immediately.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Yes, you are right, I believe the same.